# Frobenius Theorem, a Proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

I would find the proof of Frobenius Theorem (Differential Topology).

**Statement:** Let $\mathbb{S}$ an overdetermined homogenuous first order PDEs system. $\mathbb{S}$ admits unique maximal solution if and only if $\mathbb{S}$ is involutive.

I know that following conditions are equivalent:

1. $\mathbb{S}$ is integrable,
2. $\mathbb{S}$ is completely integrable,
3. $\mathbb{S}$ is involutive.

Where could I find the proof I required?
Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried searching on Wikipedia? If so is there anything you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29). But I did not found the proof

Comment: See if [this](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Sherwood.pdf) helps.

Comment: No, where does this PDF talk about what I required?

Comment: It says in the abstract that it proves Frobenius somewhere, however I'm not knowledgeable in topology so I'll shut up for now :D.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway

Comment: Every book on differentiable manifolds will have this. Boothby and Spivak (volume 1 of his 5-volume *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*) are two.

Comment: I saw this text, but there is not the proof I required.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a proof in chapter 1 of Warner's book *Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups*, starting on page 41.

Comment: Thank you for hint, but Warner's book does not deal about PDEs systems... . Thx anyway

Comment: @Puck But Warner’s book does, in  fact, deal with PDEs. A distribution is essentially a system of first order PDEs, and an integral manifold is a solution to the system. Since it is not possible to tell from your question why the Frobenius theorem proved in Warner is not an answer to it, perhaps you should give rigorous definitions and a precise statement of the result you wish to understand.

Comment: I found [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~jchaidez/materials/reu/lee_smooth_manifolds.pdf) the answer to my question. In effect, Stephen, you were right. Thx again